# OpenCV - cvExtractSURF is causing a memory leak?

Tags: c++, c, graphics, opencv

I am using the OpenCV function: `cvExtractSURF` but I am finding a major memory leak. Has anyone successfully implemented this call?

My code is as follows:

```
IplImage *cvImage = [self CreateIplImageFromUIImage:image grayscale:YES];

CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

CvSeq *objectKeypoints = 0;
//CvSeq *objectDescriptors = 0;

CvSURFParams params = cvSURFParams(self.hessianThreshold, 0);
double tt = (double)cvGetTickCount();

//Extract the features
cvExtractSURF( cvImage, 0, &objectKeypoints, NULL, storage, params, 0);

tt = (double)cvGetTickCount() - tt;
//NSLog(@"%d features found in %gms seconds\n", objectKeypoints->total, tt/(cvGetTickFrequency()*1000.));

cvReleaseImage(&cvImage);
cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage);
```

Any ideas where this could be leaking? When I comment out the line:

```
cvExtractSURF( cvImage, 0, &objectKeypoints, NULL, storage, params, 0);
```

no leak occurs.

Comment: dear @aserbin3, if you want to do the opencv community a favour, - stop editing 4-year old posts about the (then already) dead c-api. those noobs coming here will only think, it's still valid. (it is not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function cvExtractSURF creates a list of objects of type CvSURFPoint and puts a pointer to it in objectKeypoints.  You have to free that up.

Add a call...

```
cvRelease((void **)&objectKeypoints);
```

Comment: Green check mark earned :) I actually had to use cvRelease((void **)&objectKeypoints); Not too sure why this works.

Comment: Right.  cvRelease works via ad hoc polymorphism, which is why you need the cast.  I was too lazy to test the code, or I would have caught that.  I've updated the answer to include the cast.  Oh. And thanks for the check mark.